# Google MyBusiness REST API update posts PATCH method request error

Tags: php, laravel, google-api, httprequest, google-api-php-client

I want to update a specific post on google my business. I already got the `account_id`, `location_id`, and the `post_id`. I am using the url `https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/{name=accounts/*/locations/*/localPosts/*}` and doing `PATCH` method in my backend. But when I do an update it gets me an

```
 "code": 2,
 "field": "update_mask",
 "message": "update_mask is required"
```

I cant understand the `update_mask` thing in google. Can someone tell me what I should do about this? I am using laravel btw and curl library for http request. Here is my code

```
    public function updatePost(Request $request ){
        $url = 'https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/'.$request->account_id.'/locations/'.$request->location_id.'/localPosts/'.$request->post_id;
        $body['languageCode'] = "en-US";
        $body['summary'] = $request->summary;
        $body['callToAction'] = ['actionType'=> 'Call'];
        $body['media'][] = ['mediaFormat'=> 'PHOTO', "sourceUrl" => $request->imageURL];

        //Static Token only since for testing

        $headers = array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Accept: application/json',
            'Authorization: Bearer '.'ya29.a0AfH6SMB_1iUG11qj72p-pn_gCkOjUEf-ctvTGnJZ6FNTUy0Q3dYP54TMvI0cr8o0ditLp7CaWOUX5CTWn4v2kyQ-hZKSyuEJu_rBYX7uxvX373I9iVRxoypIZ6xhWDYTr-A_DHcaxGPVs1yz5u-fkYvU-xDppkASNbg'
        );

        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PATCH');
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($body));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        $response = curl_exec($curl);

        dd($response);

    }
```

The full message

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.mybusiness.v4.ValidationError",
        "errorDetails": [
          {
            "code": 2,
            "field": "update_mask",
            "message": "update_mask is required"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The docs for patch method
https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.localPosts/patch

Answer (score 1):

You need to set query parameters for the upateMask like following.

```
https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/2323232334343/locations/232323232/localPosts/23232323232?updateMask=summary
```

However, I can not edit the other field, for example, title.

Did you find the way of editting the others?

Answer (score 0):

Its clear state that you need to set query parameter 'updatemask' to a field that you want to update. Check [this doc](https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/posts-data#edit_posts) for details.